# Question about the third argument of Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm learning about derivatives. This is my code:

```
Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}]
   t1 = f[x0 + δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal ) /. (x - x0) -> δ
   t2 = f[x0 + 2 δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal) /. (x - x0) -> 2 δ
   (f'[x0] /. Solve[{t1, t2}, f'[x0], f''[x0]]) // First // Collect[#, δ, Simplify] &
```

I don't know why the third argument of the solve could be `f''[x0]`,for it is not domin.

Sorry,I didn't express it clear.I'm learning express  higher-order approximations to derivatives using this link(http://sites.apam.columbia.edu/courses/ap1601y/) with the 2-FiniteDifference.nb .

```
Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}]
t1 = f[x0 + δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal ) /. (x - x0) -> δ
t2 = f[x0 + 2 δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal) /. (x - x0) -> 2 δ
t3 = f[x0-δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal)/. (x - x0) -> -δ 
t4 = f[x0-2δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal)/. (x - x0) -> -2δ
(f'[x0] /. Solve[{t1, t2, t3, t4}, f'[x0], {f''[x0],f'''[x0],f''''[x0]}]  ) // First//Collect[#,δ, Simplify]&
```

What confuse me is why expression like  {f''[x0],f'''[x0],f''''[x0]} can be domin.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I presume you are asking about the warning message, `Solve::bdomv: Warning: (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x0] is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate. >>`.  Please read the documentation of `Solve` to see that the only valid third argument of this function  is a `domain`.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If solving for more than one unknown, they must be in a list. Per documentation.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Actually that's not pragmatically true; see [(41247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41247/121).

Comment: jesns smith, I *think* understand your question and I have tentatively marked it as a duplicate.  Please review that question (linked at the top of yours) and tell me if this answers your question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Thank you for the reference.  Evidently, inserting variables as the third argument of `Solve` (and `Reduce`) generally produces valid answers despite warning messages. Is this documented anywhere?  I reread the `Solve` documentation without seeing it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I don't believe it is documented beyond the legacy versions and in Daniel's comment below my answer to the linked question.  If I find otherwise I'll try to remember to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you mean

```
Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}]
   t1 = f[x0 + δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal ) /. (x - x0) -> δ
   t2 = f[x0 + 2 δ] == (Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] // Normal) /. (x - x0) -> 2 δ
   (f'[x0] /. Solve[{t1, t2}, {f'[x0], f''[x0]}]) // First // Collect[#, δ, Simplify] &
```

which eliminates the warning message.  I enclosed what were the second and third arguments of `Solve` in curly brackets, making them collectively the second argument.  Of course, this may not be what you had in mind.  If not, please clarify your question.