# How to eliminate variables when using Solve[]

Tags: equation-solving

In certain problems, we need to solve systems of equations and get results in terms of just selected variables.  For example, how could we solve `eqn==0` below for `c3` and `c4` expressed in terms of `c1` and `c2` only, without `a1` or `a2`?

```
eqn = {{c1, c2}, {c1, c3}, {c1, c4}, {c2, c3}}.{a1, a2} - {5, 2, -4, -3}
```

We can select two equations from the system and solve them for `a1` and `a2`, then substitute those results back in...

```
asoln = Solve[eqn[[{1, 2}]] == 0, {a1, a2}];
b = eqn /. asoln;
Solve[b == 0, {c3, c4}]

(*  {{c3 -> 1/5 (3 c1 + 2 c2), c4 -> 1/5 (9 c1 - 4 c2)}} *)
```

This approach works but it requires that we find a subset of equations from which `a1` and `a2` can be solved for unambiguously, which might be difficult.  Is it possible to make `Solve[]` eliminate `a1` and `a2` for us?

Comment: Why not `Solve[Eliminate[eqn == 0, {a1, a2}], {c3, c4}]`?

Comment: Yep, I saw it, nice find. Could you show a minimal example that fails?

Comment: Although this question should remain to improve searches I think it can be marked as a duplicate of [(41247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41247/121) unless a better solution is proposed here.  (Despite this you've got my vote on both question and answer for raising awareness of this.)

Comment: @Kuba  On rechecking my results, I think the "failures" I experienced happened for other reasons, because I couldn't re-generate any.  Maybe what you proposed above is exactly what Solve[] does "under the hood" when when given an elim argument?

Comment: @Kuba What kind of answer do you have?  If it is about the elims parameter of `Solve` or `Reduce` I think it should go in the older Q&A; or is it a different approach to the same problem?

Comment: @Kuba Post it here.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok, thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out `Solve[]` has a feature that doesn't appear in the online documentation that I could find.  A third argument can be added, a list of variables to be eliminated from the solution:

```
Solve[eqns == 0, {c3, c4}, {a1, a2}]
```

This yield the same output as above.  And I have tested it on problems where solving for `a1` and `a2` (in order to eliminate them from the system) requires a careful choice of equation subset.

`Reduce[]` has an analogous third argument discussed here:
[Behavior of Reduce with variables as domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41247)

Comment: [It was documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html), once upon a time. A pity that it isn't anymore.

Comment: @J.M.  Yeeeah...  Why is that?  I've been using MMa less than a year, so a lot of conspicuous absences in the documentation and features are bewildering to me.  Was there some Dilbert-esque political battle at WRC?

Comment: It is no longer documented because `Solve` and `Reduce` now have a third argument indicating domain over which to solve, and this is a very different beast than the original third arg. That earlier third arg is still supported though (as of this time at least).

Comment: @J. M. It comes as a surprise that the syntax has been changed.  Version 7 documentation shows the "old" form.  I felt this was worthy of an answer of itself, assuming that this question is not closed, so I posted one below.

Comment: Finally, a clear case of something **not** easily found in the documentation. :)

Comment: As I had posted with [another question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/behavior-of-reduce-with-variables-as-domain/41263?noredirect=1#comment227561_41263) for `Reduce` (cf. Mr.Wizard's entry below). The feature is still documented and can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html).

Answer (score 5):

Just to complement the topic:

```
Solve[ Eliminate[eqn == 0, {a1, a2}], {c3, c4}]
```

Comment: I have discovered that Eliminate returns some helpful error messages that Solve (with 3rd argument) does not.  Could this be why Wolfram took that 3rd argument out of their Solve[] documentation?
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84032/how-to-speed-or-help-solve-when-it-is-stuck

Answer (score 3):

This question is nearly a duplicate of [Behavior of Reduce with variables as domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41247/121) but since it is being addressed separately I shall answer here as well.  In [the documentation for version 7](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html) (which I used for an extended time) it starts with:

[image]

In version 8 this was changed to a domain specification, but where distinguishable the older syntax still works.  For now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you include the intermediate variables in the Solve list then Mathematica will try and find solutions for those as well:

```
sys = {{c1, c2}, {c1, c3}, {c1, c4}, {c2, c3}}.{a1, a2} == {5, 2, -4, -3};
Solve[sys, {c3, c4, a1, a2}]
```

Gives: {{c3 -> 1/5 (3 c1 + 2 c2), c4 -> 1/5 (9 c1 - 4 c2), a1 -> 5/(c1 - c2), a2 -> -(5/(c1 - c2))}}

Comment: My one reservation is that on very large, complicated, non-linear calculations, this method makes MMa grind out results that weren't needed.