# How to speed or help Solve[] when it is stuck?

Tags: equation-solving

The code below generates a system of equations that I need to Solve[] for {c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]} in terms of {c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]}.

```
f[x_] := E^-Sum[a[i]*x^i, {i, 0, 4}];
zeroEq = {};
Do[Do[
   zeroEq = Append[zeroEq, Expand[D[f[x]*x^n, {x, m}]/f[x]] /. x^r_ -> c[r] /. x -> c[1]],
   {n, 0, 8 - 3*m}], {m, 1, 2}];
aElim = Eliminate[zeroEq == 0, {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}];
```

This much works fine, but then Solve[] just runs indefinitely without returning results or error messages.

```
Solve[aElim, {c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]}]
```

I attempted applying some known inequalities to reduce the work on Solve[], but Reduce[] bogs down in the same way, no error message or result:

```
Reduce[aElim && c[2] > 0 && c[4] > 0 && c[6] > 0 && c[8] > 0]
```

So...

1) what is going on here?
2) Can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you *don't* include the inequalities? Also, it looks to me that you are equating an entire list (`eqn`) to 0; without `Thread[]`, I can imagine how it might cause some trouble.

Comment: (1) `Solve` is fine with `Solve[list==0]` and just quietly thread over one level. (2) I suspect `Eliminate` is not happy with inequalities though.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I changed the code to remove the inequalities, ran into the same problem.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  I changed the code to remove the inequalities, ran into the same problem.

Comment: Is the solution going to be used for numerical calculations in Mathematica afterwards? Or you are more interested in getting a formal solution to the problem?

Comment: @Bichoy  Only a formal solution would be useful.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Is this a BUG in MMa?  It seems like it should either give an error message or give up or get a result, not grind on forever and return nothing.  It actually wouldn't even let me Alt-, once and I had to restart.

Answer (score 4):

One can use `GroebnerBasis` to eliminate variables, and it is set up in a way that tends to be more efficient than `Eliminate` (which may be using some dated technology).

```
polys = {-a[1] - 2 a[2] c[1] - 3 a[3] c[2] - 4 a[4] c[3], 
   1 - a[1] c[1] - 2 a[2] c[2] - 3 a[3] c[3] - 4 a[4] c[4], 
   2 c[1] - a[1] c[2] - 2 a[2] c[3] - 3 a[3] c[4] - 4 a[4] c[5], 
   3 c[2] - a[1] c[3] - 2 a[2] c[4] - 3 a[3] c[5] - 4 a[4] c[6], 
   4 c[3] - a[1] c[4] - 2 a[2] c[5] - 3 a[3] c[6] - 4 a[4] c[7], 
   5 c[4] - a[1] c[5] - 2 a[2] c[6] - 3 a[3] c[7] - 4 a[4] c[8], 
   a[1]^2 - 2 a[2] + 4 a[1] a[2] c[1] - 6 a[3] c[1] + 4 a[2]^2 c[2] + 
    6 a[1] a[3] c[2] - 12 a[4] c[2] + 12 a[2] a[3] c[3] + 
    8 a[1] a[4] c[3] + 9 a[3]^2 c[4] + 16 a[2] a[4] c[4] + 
    24 a[3] a[4] c[5] + 16 a[4]^2 c[6], -2 a[1] + a[1]^2 c[1] - 
    6 a[2] c[1] + 4 a[1] a[2] c[2] - 12 a[3] c[2] + 4 a[2]^2 c[3] + 
    6 a[1] a[3] c[3] - 20 a[4] c[3] + 12 a[2] a[3] c[4] + 
    8 a[1] a[4] c[4] + 9 a[3]^2 c[5] + 16 a[2] a[4] c[5] + 
    24 a[3] a[4] c[6] + 16 a[4]^2 c[7], 
   2 - 4 a[1] c[1] + a[1]^2 c[2] - 10 a[2] c[2] + 4 a[1] a[2] c[3] - 
    18 a[3] c[3] + 4 a[2]^2 c[4] + 6 a[1] a[3] c[4] - 28 a[4] c[4] + 
    12 a[2] a[3] c[5] + 8 a[1] a[4] c[5] + 9 a[3]^2 c[6] + 
    16 a[2] a[4] c[6] + 24 a[3] a[4] c[7] + 16 a[4]^2 c[8]};
avars = {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]};
cvars = {c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]};

Timing[
 gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, cvars, avars, 
    MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder, Sort -> True];]

(* Out[199]= {0., Null} *)
```

It's not giving a small result though.

```
In[202]:= gb // LeafCount

(* Out[202]= 67818 *)

In[203]:= Length[gb]

(* Out[203]= 15 *)
```

So further processing e.g. in `Reduce` might still bog down.

Comment: I had gotten into the habit of using `GroebnerBasis[]` to build implicit equations from the parametric representations of algebraic curves, but had always been wondering "shouldn't I be able to use `Eliminate[]` for this?". Now, you mention that `Eliminate[]` "may be using some dated technology"; I guess it was difficult to get the Gröbner stuff to play nice with everything else?

Comment: @Guess who it is I don't actually know how much trouble it is, or even what exactly `Eliminate` is now doing. It might be that it was never overhauled in the way that `Solve` was. Or maybe it was, and is falling short for other reasons.