# How to determine why Solve[] failed?

Tags: equation-solving

I don't know what to make of Solve[] failing on this:

```
exp[x_] := Sum[a[i]*x^i, {i, 0, 4}];
f[x_] := E^exp[x];
zeroEq = {};
Do[Do[
   zeroEq = Append[zeroEq, Expand[D[f[x]*x^n, {x, m}]/f[x]] /. x^r_ -> c[r] /. x -> c[1]],
   {n, 0, 8 - 3*m}], {m, 1, 2}];
Do[
 zeroEq = Append[zeroEq, Expand[D[exp[x]*f[x]*x^n, x]/f[x]] /. x^r_ -> c[r] /. x -> c[1]], 
 {n, 0, 1}]
Solve[zeroEq == 0, {c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]}]
```

This returns empty brackets.  But if I add a known inequality c[4]<0 to the Solve[] expression, then MMa grinds on forever without returning a result or an error message:

```
Solve[zeroEq == 0 && c[4] < 0, {c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]}]
```

If the system has no solution, why would adding the inequality make MMa fail to find that?  Or does it have a solution that MMa is just missing?

I also tried this:

```
elims = Flatten[{Table[d[i], {i, 1, 16}], Table[a[j], {j, 1, 4}]}];
Solve[r == 0, {c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]}, elims, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

And again, MMa just grinds forever, no result or error message.  So I tried this:

```
Solve[r[[Table[i, {i, 1, 27}]]] == 0, {c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]}, elims]
```

The first 26 conditions create an underdetermined system, so 27 conditions be correctly determined.  It should be VERY easy to solve a linear problem like this, but MMa bogs down.  Why?

This issue is related to [THIS discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84032/121), so if the Answers are related maybe the Questions should be merged.  But I'm so puzzled I'm not sure if I'm running into the same problem or a different one or just a "feature".  Plus, I asked the first Question unaware of certain quirks of Solve[] like the inexplicable failure example above.

(BTW, if anyone cares, I'm trying to calculate the 5th-8th moments c[5]-c[8] of a 1-D pdf f[x], where f[x] maximizes entropy with the constraints of known 1st-4th moments c[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84032/121)-c[4].  To do this, I'm generating definite integrals of derivs of various quantities, all of which equal 0.  So this system MUST have a solution, unless I've just calculated some of the equalities wrong.)

Comment: `Solve[x == 1 && y == 2, {x}]` returning an empty solution set is correct, and documented behavior, and not related to the rest of the post as best I can tell. As for the documentation, see the Details section in the ref guide page for Solve: "With `MaxExtraConditions->Automatic`, only solutions that require the minimal number of equational conditions on continuous parameters are included." In this case, there is an equational condition imposed, to wit, `y==2`, and the default setting is `MaxExtraConditions->0`.

Comment: @MarcoB The experts on this site assure me that {list}==0 is okay.  Try this demo and see:   n = 10; sys = RandomInteger[{-2 n, 2 n}, {n, n}].Table[w[i], {i, 1, n}]; Solve[ sys - 1 == 0]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a c[0] in your zeroEq. Does that expose an error in the construction? Reduce[zeroEq, {c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8]}, Backsubstitution -> True] does find a solution to your system if some of your other coefficients have appropriate values and you use the correct "==0" syntax inside Reduce.

Comment: @Bill  No, the c[0] doesn't appear in the code at all, so that's not the issue.  I'll remove it from the text.  And c[1]-c[4] are all constants.  What did you mean by the correct "==0"?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Ah, thank you.  I removed that first example, since now I know it's not related to my main issue.  I tried MaxExtraConditions->All, but that didn't fix the problem either.  I added this example.

Comment: Possibly the issue is that `Solve` is now using different methods (due to a restriction that a variable be real-valued), and these methods might be slower in this case than those for handling general complex-valued solutions. As `Solve` does not use the latter first, it has no way to realize that the solution set is empty. This is just speculation on my part in that I've not checked, but it is a likely explanation.