# solve nonlinear differential equations for some variables

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I have a few nonlinear differential equations and some variables that I need them to be eliminated when I am calculating differential equations based on other 3 variables, but I can just get an answer for 2 variables. Can somebody please notify me about my mistake? what am I doing wrong? Here are my equations and elims:

```
equations := {C1c1*Iin1[t] == ToutBeta1 + FIoutBeta1''[t]*C1c6, 
  TinBeta2 == 
   C2c3*FIinBeta2''[t] + C2c1*(FIinBeta2[t] - thetaB2[t]) + 
    C2c6*(FIinBeta2'[t] - thetaB2'[t]), 
  C2c4*thetaB2''[t] + C2c1*(thetaB2[t] - FIinBeta2[t]) + 
    C2c6*(thetaB2'[t] - FIinBeta2'[t]) + Ff2*C2c2/(2*pi) == 0, 
  C2c5*YoutY2''[t] == Ff2 - FoutY2, 
  thetaB2[t] == (2*pi/C2c2)*YoutY2[t], 
  thetaB2'[t] == (2*pi/C2c2)*YoutY2'[t], 
  thetaB2''[t] == (2*pi/C2c2)*YoutY2''[t], 
  C3c1*Iin3[t] == ToutGamma3 + FIoutGamma3''[t]*C3c6, 
  FoutY3 + C3c3*YoutY3''[t] == FinY3, YoutY3''[t] == YinY3''[t], 
  TinGamma4 - C4c1*Sin[FIinGamma4[t]]*FoutY4 - 
    C4c1*Cos[FIinGamma4[t]]*FoutX4 - 
    1/2*C4c1*Sin[FIinGamma4[t]]*C4c4*YinY4''[t] == 
   C4c3*FIinGamma4''[t], 
  YinY4[t] == YoutY4[t] - C4c1*Cos[FIinGamma4[t]], 
  YinY4'[t] == YoutY4'[t] + C4c1*FinGamma'[t]*Sin[FIinGamma4[t]], 
  YinY4''[t] == 
   YoutY4''[t] + C4c1*FIinGamma4''[t]*Sin[FIinGamma4[t]] + 
    C4c1*((FIinGamma4'[t])^2)*Cos[FIinGamma4[t]], 
  FIinGamma4[t] == ArcSin[YoutX4[t]/C4c1], 
  FIinGamma4'[
    t] == (YoutX4'[t])/(C4c1*(1 - ((YoutX4[t])^2)/C4c1^2)^(1/2)), 
  FIinGamma4''[t] == 
   YoutX4''[t]/(C4c1*(1 - ((YoutX4[t])^2)/(C4c1^2))^(1/2)) + (YoutX4[
        t]*(YoutX4'[t])^2)/(C4c1^3*(1 - ((YoutX4[t])^2)/(C4c1^2))^(3/
          2)), FoutX4 + C4c4*(YoutX4''[t] + YinX4''[t])/2 == FinX4, 
  FoutY4 + C4c4*(YoutY4''[t] + YinY4''[t])/2 == FinY4, 
  C5c4*YinX5''[t] == FinX5 - FoutX5, YinX5''[t] == YoutX5''[t], 
  C5c5*YinY5''[t] == FinY5 - FoutY5, YinY5''[t] == YoutY5''[t], 
  ToutBeta1 == TinBeta2, FIoutBeta1[t] == FIinBeta2[t], 
  FIoutBeta1'[t] == FIinBeta2'[t], FIoutBeta1''[t] == FIinBeta2''[t], 
  FoutY2 == FinY3, YoutY2[t] == YinY3[t], YoutY2'[t] == YinY3'[t], 
  YoutY2''[t] == YinY3''[t], ToutGamma3 == TinGamma4, FoutX3 == FinX4,
   FoutY3 == FinY4, FIoutGamma3[t] == FIinGamma4[t], 
  FIoutAlpha3'[t] == FIinAlpha4'[t], FIoutBeta3'[t] == FIinBeta4'[t], 
  FIoutGamma3'[t] == FIinGamma4'[t], 
  FIoutGamma3''[t] == FIinGamma4''[t], YoutX3[t] == YinX4[t], 
  YoutY3[t] == YinY4[t], YoutX3'[t] == YinX4'[t], 
  YoutY3'[t] == YinY4'[t], YoutX3''[t] == YinX4''[t], FoutX4 == FinX5,
   FoutY4 == FinY5, YoutX4[t] == YinX5[t], YoutY4[t] == YinY5[t], 
  YoutX4'[t] == YinX5'[t], YoutY4'[t] == YinY5'[t], 
  YoutX4''[t] == YinX5''[t], YoutY4''[t] == YinY5''[t], FoutX5 == 0, 
  FoutY5 == 0}
```

my elims:

```
elims := {ToutBeta1, TinBeta2, FIinBeta2[t], YoutY2[t], FoutY2,
FIinBeta2'[t], FIinBeta2''[t], YoutY2'[t], YoutY2''[t], ToutGamma3,
YinX3[t], YinY3[t], YoutY3[t], FinX3, FinY3, FoutX3, FoutY3, 
YinX3'[t], YinY3'[t], YinX3''[t], YinY3''[t], YoutX3'[t],
YoutY3'[t], YoutX3''[t], YoutY3''[t], TinGamma4, YinX4[t], YinY4[t],
FinX4, FinY4, FoutX4, FoutY4, YinX4'[t], YinY4'[t], YinX4''[t],
YinY4''[t], YinX5[t], YinY5[t], YoutX5[t], YoutY5[t], FinX5, FinY5,
FoutX5, FoutY5, YinX5'[t], YinY5'[t], YinX5''[t], YinY5''[t], 
YoutX5'[t], YoutY5'[t], YoutX5''[t], YoutY5''[t], Ff2, thetaB2[t],
thetaB2'[t], thetaB2''[t], FIoutGamma3[t], FIoutGamma3'[t],
FIoutGamma3''[t]}
```

and I use: `dynamic := {FIoutBeta1''[t], YoutX4''[t], YoutY4''[t]}`

with: `Equal @@@ Flatten[First@Solve[(Eliminate[equations, elims] // FullSimplify), dynamic]]`
I can just get answer for `YoutX4` and `YoutY4`, I can't get an answer for `FIoutBeta1`!

Comment: The system of equations obtained after `Eliminate[equations, elims]`, does not have `FIoutBeta1[t]`. That is the reason why it doesn't return any solution for `FIoutBeta1[t]`.

Comment: @AnjanKumar but I am not eliminating FIoutBeta1, so why it is disappeared?

Comment: @Feyre Thanks but that's not the problem, since when I am removing it again there is no answer! although that is a constraint and I cannot remove it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized and unlikely to help future vistors.

Comment: @xzczd if you have any solution for it, first suggest it and then vote!

Comment: @xzczd If it is a fundamental flaw in the way `Eliminate[]` operates, it's not too localized.

Comment: @Feyre OK, next time I'll consider using a more proper reason for voting. BTW, it's probably not a flaw of `Eliminate`, but the nature of the equation set. There're 54 equations, but 59 variables to eliminate!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I investigated my own code deeply. Apparently, there is a problem with `Elimination` command that cannot eliminate some variables which are directly related to nonlinear equations or inside nonlinear equations. In my equations I am eliminating `thetaB2[t]` which is equal to `(2*pi/C2c2)*YoutY2[t]`, and `YoutY2[t]==YinY3[t]`, `YinY3[t]==YoutY4[t]` and finally,  `YinY4[t] == YoutY4[t] - C4c1*Cos[FIinGamma4[t]]` and `FIinGamma4[t] == ArcSin[YoutX4[t]/C4c1]`. `Eliminate` works mainly with polynomial equations and may be able to handle simple transcendental functions. Apparently, `Eliminate` ignores everything it can not handle. So whenever I am removing `thetaB2[t]` I get an answer for `FIoutBeta1''[t]` too, but it's not the desired answer which I am after.

[image]

Comment: -1. _Mathematica_ does have bugs and limitations, but doubting about its capability should always be the last thing to do. The current situation is (1) `Eliminate` and `Solve` are both frequently used i.e. heavily tested function, and have been proved to be robust. (2) So long nobody seems to observe similar problem in this site. (Just search "[bugs] [equation-solving]" here. ) (3) Your equation set is a mess involving 54 equation and you give no evidence that `FIoutBeta1''[t]` is **independent** with variables inside `elims`. Apparently, your words are lame.

Comment: try to be polite if you do not have enough information, just search and read a little bit about Elimination, it is obviously mentioned about limitations of it! @xzczd and try to test this example with removing thetaB, then you might understand the problem of it!
In case that you don't have any new information to it, just ignore this question and skip it, instead of arguing the wrong things!

Comment: With all due respect, if there's anybody being impolite in this post, it's you. I know `Eliminate` and `Solve` have their limitations, what I'm argued with my answer and comments is, your problem isn't caused by those limitations, while so long you give no effective disproof. You're essentially saying "there's nothing wrong with my system, it's a flaw of `Eliminate`" without giving any credible evidence over and over. (A equation system formed by 54 equations with no explanation for how you deduce it won't convince anybody. )

Answer (score 2):

OK, let me offer a free debugging service to contend this question is off topic in a more effective way. First, consider a simpler problem:

> Why doesn't
>
> ```
> Solve[Eliminate[{a == e, b == 1}, a], {b, e}]
> ```
>
> give answer for `e`?

The answer is obvious: if `a` is eliminated from the equation set, `e` will disappear, too. **`e` isn't independent with `a`.** If such a question is posted in this site, I'm sure it'll be considered as a simple mistake.

**OP has essentially asked the same question.**

Let's eliminate the variables in `elims` one by one:

```
midlst = elims;
i = 0;
dat = FoldList[(midlst = DeleteCases[midlst, #2]; 
     Equal @@@ Flatten@Solve[#, Flatten@{dynamic, midlst}, {#2}]) &, equations, elims];
```

I've made use of the [hidden syntax of `Solve`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83904/1871) because it's more efficient. Then, check when `FIoutBeta1''[t]` disappears:

```
! FreeQ[#, FIoutBeta1''[t]] & /@ dat
(* …, True, False, False, False, False} *)
```

Fifth to last equation set in `dat` is suspicious. Which of them involve `FIoutBeta1''[t]`? 3rd of them:

```
! FreeQ[#, FIoutBeta1''[t]] & /@ dat[[-5]]
(* {False, False, True, False, False, False} *)
```

Which of them involve the variable to be eliminated next? 3rd of them!:

```
! FreeQ[#, elims[[-4]]] & /@ dat[[-5]]
(* {False, False, True, False, False, False} *)
```

Then `FIoutBeta1''[t]` disappears together with `elims[[-4]]`, just as what happened at beginning of this answer. (Notice if the order of `elims` differs, the variable tied with `FIoutBeta1''[t]` will probably different, too. ) `FIoutBeta1''[t]` is **not** independent with one or more variables in `elims`.

That's the reason for my voting to close as off-topic, haven't yet decided the specific reason, "simple mistake", "too localized", "asking for free debugging service", probably one of them.

Comment: obviously you did not get that these equations are dynamic equations of a model based system, so eliminating each of the variables which are linked to FIoutBeta1 won't cause a problem, that's what you do when you solve differential equations manually! @xzczd
also, the simple example you mentioned is irrelevant to this question! since in my case 'e' is a connective variable between two or three equations.

Comment: @FaribaRahimi  What I do with my code is exactly what one does when eliminating the variable from the equation set manually. Notice in your case `FIoutBeta1''[t]` and `elims` are not simply "linked" or "connected", they are **dependent**! You're essentially claiming "`Solve[Eliminate[{b + a - 1 == e, 2 e + b == 1 + 2 a}, a], {b, e}]` should give answer for `e`, because in this case `e` is a connective variable between two equations."

Comment: I am afraid that again you are mistaken, the similarity of your simple case to my equations would be to eliminate 'e' and find a result for 'a' or 'b' as an example. @xzczd

Comment: "the similarity of your simple case to my equations would be to eliminate 'e' and find a result for **'a'** or 'b' as an example." Are you sure? Have you tried it yourself? `Solve[Eliminate[{b + a - 1 == e, 2 e + b == 1 + 2 a}, e], {a}]` @FaribaRahimi

Comment: please try this as simple example:
(Solve[Eliminate[{b + a - 2 +d== -e,  e + b == 1 + 2 a, e==a}, {b, e}], a]), which gives an answer of a=(1-d)/3, although you are eliminating 'e' which is equal to 'a'
@xzczd Yes, I am sure, because I am not eliminating 'FIoutBeta1' itself, I am eliminating 'FIinBeta2' which is equal to 'FIoutBeta1'.

Comment: @FaribaRahimi First of all, it is quite hard to read the system of equations/odes because of the weird `Youk2` and others...Besides, The issue is with the system. `Eliminate` does what it suppose to do.

Comment: @FaribaRahimi But in the example you give, `{a, b, e}` is **independent**! Try `Solve[{b + a - 2 + d == -e, e + b == 1 + 2 a, e == a}, {b, e, a}]` And what I've argued with my answer is, `FIoutBeta1''[t]` is **not** independent with one or more variables inside `elims`. In other words, something is wrong with your equation set, please re-check it. It's not rare at all that such a mess of code contains mistake(s).