# Rewriting algebraic expressions as combinations of other expressions

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to write `x^5 + 1/x^5` in terms of `x^2 + 1/x^2`, `x^3 + 1/x^3` and `x + 1/x` or  express `x^6 + 1/x^6` in terms of `x^2 + 1/x^2` and `x^4 + 1/x^4` etc.

How can I do that in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Have a look at: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83902/how-to-eliminate-variables-when-using-solve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special approach with `Solve` eliminating appropriate variables, e.g. in the following `x` should be eliminated

```
a/. Solve[{x^5 + 1/x^5 == a, x^3 + 1/x^3 == b, x^2 + 1/x^2 == c, x + 1/x == d},
      {a, b, d}, {x}]
```

> ```
> {-Sqrt[2 + 5 c - 5 c^3 + c^5], Sqrt[2 + 5 c - 5 c^3 + c^5]}
> ```

or e.g.

```
Solve[{ x^5 + 1/x^5 == a, x^3 + 1/x^3 == b, x^2 + 1/x^2 == c, x + 1/x == d}, 
       {a, b, c}, {x}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> d (5 - 5 d^2 + d^4), b -> d (-3 + d^2), c -> -2 + d^2}}
> ```

The above demonstrates that there is no unique method providing the best solution unless we define precisely what the best approach means. We can express `a` in terms of `c` only as well as in terms of `d` only. Nevertheless one can easily observe that

```
a == b c - d /.First @ Solve[{x^5 + 1/x^5 == a, x^3 + 1/x^3 == b, 
                              x^2 + 1/x^2 == c, x + 1/x == d}, 
                             {a, b, c}, {x}] // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

as well as e.g.

```
a == d (c^2 - c - 1)/.First @ Solve[{x^5 + 1/x^5 == a, x^3 + 1/x^3 == b,
                                      x^2 + 1/x^2 == c, x + 1/x == d},      
                                    {a, b, c}, {x}] // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Another way is a standard approach with `Eliminate`, e.g.

```
Eliminate[{x^6 + 1/x^6 == e, x^4 + 1/x^4 == f, x^2 + 1/x^2 == c},
          {x, f}]
```

> ```
> e == -3 c + c^3
> ```

and it appears that with `Solve` we can produce another representation of `e`:

```
e == f c - c /.First @ Solve[{ x^6 + 1/x^6 == e, x^4 + 1/x^4 == f,
                                x^2 + 1/x^2 == c}, {e, f}, {x} // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

These methods work quite satisfactory when the list of equations is rather short and we expect one can improve solutions if we appropriately restrict the solution space.

Answer (score 6):

@Artes lready showed how one might use `Solve` or `Eliminate` for this task. Since it involves algebraic rewriting of a rational expression, a standard method from computational algebra involves Groebner bases. Technical-sounding, yes, but also quite powerful.

The idea is to write the inputs as polynomials. I use `y` as the reciprocal of `x` and add a polynomial relation `x*y-1` to enforce this. I equate each target polynomial to a new "marker" (or "tag") variable. The code for this is written in a way that is intended to be readily automated, that is, to systems with more relations, different variables, etc.

```
basepolys = {x^3 + y^3, x^2 + y^2, x + y};
avars = Array[a, Length[basepolys]];
allpolys = Join[avars - basepolys, {x*y - 1}];
allvars = Join[Variables[basepolys], avars];
```

Next compute a Groebner basis using a term order that places the original variables "larger" than the marker variables. This will make rewrites favor the marker variables over the polynomial variables.

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, allvars];
```

Now we can rewrite that input `x^5+1/x^5 like so:

```
PolynomialReduce[x^5 + y^5, gb, allvars][[2]]

(* Out[1322]= 5 a[3] - 5 a[3]^3 + a[3]^5 *)
```

I left out a couple of niceties. One can programatically (as in, exercise for the reader) replace negative powers of `x`, for example. Or replace the result with explicit uses of the original expressions `x^3+1/x^3,...`.