# Arrange a system of differential equations to standard state-space equation form

Tags: differential-equations, algebraic-manipulation

[image: The circuit]
I want to model an electrical circuit in the form of state-space equations, and I want to use Mathematica to solve the final equations, the circuit equations (from Kirchhoff's law) are shown below, and the upper point indicates differential calculation.

> $$
> \dot{x}=\frac{d x}{d t}
> $$

Kirchhoff's current law:

> $$
> \begin{array}{c}i+i_{3}+x_{3}-C_{2} \dot{x}_{2}=0 \\C_{1} \dot{x}_{1}+x_{3}+x_{4}=0 \\C_{2} \dot{x}_{2}+x_{4}-i_{4}=0\end{array}
> $$

Kirchhoff's voltage law:

> $$
> \begin{array}{c}-L_{1} \dot{x}_{3}+x_{1}+R_{1} i_{3}=0 \\-x_{1}+L_{2} \dot{x}_{4}+R_{2} i_{4}=0 \\L_{2} \dot{x}_{4}-L_{1} \dot{x}_{3}-x_{2}=0\end{array}
> $$

i.e.

```
eq1 = i + i3 + x3[t] - C2*x2'[t] == 0
eq2 = C1*x1'[t] + x3[t] + x4[t] == 0
eq3 = C2*x2'[t] + x4[t] - i4 == 0
eq4 = -L1*x3'[t] + x1[t] + R1*i3 == 0
eq5 = -x1[t] + L2*x4'[t] + R2*i4 == 0
eq6 = L2*x4'[t] - L1*x3'[t] - x2[t] == 0
```

I can only simplify these equations with pen and paper, like first I eliminate two variables i3 and i4

> $$
> \begin{array}{l}\dot{x}_{1}=-\frac{1}{C_{1}} x_{3}-\frac{1}{C_{1}} x_{4} \\R_{1} C_{2} \dot{x}_{2}-L_{1} \dot{x}_{3}=-x_{1}+R_{1} x_{3}+R_{1} i \\R_{2} C_{2} \dot{x}_{2}+L_{2} \dot{x}_{4}=x_{1}-R_{2} x_{4} \\-L_{1} \dot{x}_{3}+L_{2} \dot{x}_{4}=x_{2}\end{array}$$

And then arrange them in a standard state-space equation form:

> $$
> \left(\begin{array}{l}\dot{x}_{1} \\\dot{x}_{2} \\\dot{x}_{3} \\\dot{x}_{4}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{C_{1}} & -\frac{1}{C_{1}} \\0 & -\frac{1}{C_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} & \frac{R_{1}}{C_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} & -\frac{R_{2}}{C_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} \\\frac{1}{L_{1}} & -\frac{R_{1}}{L_{1}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} & -\frac{R_{1} R_{2}}{L_{1}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} & -\frac{R_{1} R_{2}}{L_{1}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} \\\frac{1}{L_{2}} & -\frac{R_{2}}{L_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} & -\frac{R_{1} R_{2}}{L_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} & -\frac{R_{1} R_{2}}{L_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}x_{1} \\x_{2} \\x_{3} \\x_{4}\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\\frac{R_{1}}{C_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} \\-\frac{R_{1} R_{2}}{L_{1}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)} \\-\frac{R_{1} R_{2}}{L_{2}\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)}\end{array}\right) i
> $$

I've searched a lot, but I can't find any reference to help me.

Comment: is your question about using Mathematica to solve the final equations you have, or is it about how to derive the Mathematical model itself that you want Mathematica to solve? it is not clear what you are asking. If it is about how to derive the mathematical model, then I think Physics/EE will be better forum.

Comment: To eliminate `i3` and `i4` you could use, well, [Eliminate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html).

Comment: “and I want to use Mathematica to solve the final equations” Do you actually mean "and I want to use Mathematica to _derive_ the final equations"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `Eliminate` and `Solve` is OK, but it's simpler to use [hidden syntax of `Solve`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83904/1871):

```
vars = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]};

sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, D[vars, t], {i3, i4}]
```

The matrix can then be easily obtained with `CoefficientArray`:

```
coef = CoefficientArrays[sol[[1, All, -1]], vars]
MatrixForm /@ coef
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out... Although it is a set of differential equations, however, the simplifying process doesn't involve differential or integral calculation, so I just define the higher order part like x1'[t] as x1d. The equations can be written as:

```
eq1 = i + i3 + x3 - C2*x2d == 0
eq2 = C1*x1d + x3 + x4 == 0
eq3 = C2*x2d + x4 - i4 == 0
eq4 = -L1*x3d + x1 + R1*i3 == 0
eq5 = -x1 + L2*x4d + R2*i4 == 0
eq6 = L2*x4d - L1*x3d - x2 == 0
eqns = eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && eq6
```

Firstly, use 'Elimination' to eliminate i3 and i4:

```
Eliminate[eqns, {i3, i4}]
```

output[52]:

```
i R1 == C1 R1 x1d + C2 R1 x2d + C2 R2 x2d - L1 x3d + R1 x4 + R2 x4 + 
   L2 x4d && x1 == C2 R2 x2d + R2 x4 + L2 x4d && 
 x2 == -L1 x3d + L2 x4d && x3 == -C1 x1d - x4
```

Then just use Solve to separate x1d...x4d from these equations

```
MatrixForm[Solve[%52, {x1d, x2d, x3d, x4d}]]
```

output

> $$
> \left\{\left\{\text{x1d}\to -\frac{\text{x3}+\text{x4}}{\text{C1}},\text{x2d}\to -\frac{-i \text{R1}-\text{R1} \text{x3}+\text{R2} \text{x4}+\text{x2}}{\text{C2} (\text{R1}+\text{R2})},\text{x3d}\to -\frac{i \text{R1} \text{R2}+\text{R1} \text{R2} \text{x3}+\text{R1} \text{R2} \text{x4}-\text{R1} \text{x1}+\text{R1} \text{x2}-\text{R2} \text{x1}}{\text{L1} (\text{R1}+\text{R2})},\text{x4d}\to -\frac{i \text{R1} \text{R2}+\text{R1} \text{R2} \text{x3}+\text{R1} \text{R2} \text{x4}-\text{R1} \text{x1}-\text{R2} \text{x1}-\text{R2} \text{x2}}{\text{L2} (\text{R1}+\text{R2})}\right\}\right\}
> $$

Comment: True, although `Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, {x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t], x4'[t], i3, i4}][[1, ;; 4]]` , where the eq's are your original expressions, is simpler.