# Expression substitution

Tags: replacement, semantic-matching

I konw:
$$
a_0=\frac{4 \pi \epsilon_0 \hbar^2}{m_e e^2}
$$
and
$$
\alpha = \frac{m_{\mathrm{e}}^2 e^4}{18 \pi^3 \epsilon_0^2 \hbar^4}
$$

So we can use $a_0$ for $\alpha$,like this:
$$
\alpha=\frac{m_{\mathrm{e}}^2 e^4}{18 \pi^3 \epsilon_0^2 \hbar^4}=\frac{16}{18 \pi} \cdot \frac{m_{\mathrm{e}}^2 e^4}{16 \pi^2 \epsilon_0^2 \hbar^4}=\frac{8}{9 \pi} \cdot \frac{1}{a_0^2}
$$

```mathematica
alpha = (e^4 me^2)/(18 eps^2 h^4 \[Pi]^3);
a0 = (4 Pi eps h^2)/(me e^2);
```

I've tried a few things and failed. What should I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
eq1 = alpha == (e^4 me^2)/(18 eps^2 h^4 \[Pi]^3);
eq2 = a0 == (4 Pi eps h^2)/(me e^2);

Solve[{eq1, eq2}, alpha, {e}]
```

[image]

Comment: How does that work? Don't get it

Comment: In fact, this is not practical，We usually define a variable with `=` because we need to use that variable later

Comment: No problem, use: `var= alpha /. Solve[...][[1]]` You should try to learn MAthematica.

Comment: @DanielHuber Can you explain your domain parameter `{e}`?

Comment: Solve has a third argument that is no more documented, similar to Reduce (see. e.g.: https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html  or  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83902/how-to-eliminate-variables-when-using-solve). This argument specifies variables to eliminate. Why it is no more documented is beyond me. Here is a simple example: Solve[{a == b, b == c}, a, {b}]`