# Eliminate for inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Say I have

```
a > c && c > b
```

What function can eliminate c to yield:

```
a > b
```

A lot like:

```
Eliminate[a == c && c == b, c]
```

but for inequalities

Comment: I suspect `Resolve` is the function of choice for this. `In[92]:= Resolve[Exists[c, a > c && c > b], {a, b}, Reals]

Out[92]= b < a`

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly close:

```
Reduce[a > c && c > b, {a, b}, {c}]
(*  a ∈ Reals && b < a  *)
```

Reference for this (now undocumented) form of the third argument of `Solve`/`Reduce`:
[Behavior of Reduce with variables as domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/behavior-of-reduce-with-variables-as-domain)

Comment: I didn't know you can pass that as domain...

Comment: @kozner If you read Mr.Wizard's answer to the linked question, you'll see that this form for the "domain" is interpreted as a list of variables to be eliminated. It used to be documented, but the form was dropped from the documentation a few versions ago.