# How to help Mathematica Solve simple substitution equation?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

```
(* Here are two equations *) 

eqns = { 
 az == ArcTan[Cos[lat]*Sin[dec] - Cos[dec]*Cos[gmst + lon - 
 ra]*Sin[lat], -(Cos[dec]*Sin[gmst + lon - ra])], 
 ha == gmst + lon - ra 
}; 

(* should be easy... just replace gmst+lon-ra with ha in the az equation *) 

Solve[eqns, az, {ha}] // InputForm 

(* the answer, however, still contains gmst, lon, and ra *) 

{{az -> ArcTan[Cos[lat]*Sin[dec] - Cos[dec]*Cos[gmst + lon - ra]*Sin[lat],  
    -(Cos[dec]*Sin[gmst + lon - ra])]}} 

(* Eliminate won't work here ... *) 

Eliminate[eqns, {gmst, lon, ra}] // InputForm 

(* yielding this error *) 

Eliminate::dinv:  
   The expression ArcTan[Cos[lat] Sin[dec] -  
      Cos[dec] Cos[gmst + lon - ra] Sin[lat], -(Cos[dec] Sin[gmst + lon - ra])] 
    involves unknowns in more than one argument, so inverse functions cannot be 
     used. 

(* and this unhelpful output *) 

az == ArcTan[Cos[lat]*Sin[dec] - Cos[dec]*Cos[gmst + lon - ra]*Sin[lat],  
   -(Cos[dec]*Sin[gmst + lon - ra])] && gmst == ha - lon + ra
```

My question here isn't necessarily "why can't Mathematica do this?" (because that answer really doesn't help me), but "what can I do to help Mathematica solve this?"

The actual problem has many more variables and equations, but this example represents the general problem.

Comment: What about `eqns[[1]] /. Solve[eqns[[2]], gmst][[1]]`?

Comment: That works in this specific case @UlrichNeumann but won't work in general. I can post a more complete set of equations, but I need a generic solution that doesn't require human cleverness :)

Comment: `Simplify[{az == ArcTan[Cos[lat]*Sin[dec] - Cos[dec]*Cos[gmst+lon-ra]*Sin[lat], -(Cos[dec]*Sin[gmst+lon-ra])]}, {ha == gmst+lon-ra}]` will rapidly do what you are asking for, even for bigger lists and more complicated expressions, often for things where it would be very difficult for `Solve` or `Reduce` to handle. Can you perhaps find a way to automate dividing your list of equations into two lists, the second list containing those `var==expression` where `var` appears at least once in the first list and doesn't appear in expression?

Comment: @Bill I'll try this. My ultimate goal is to get everything in terms of everything else to the extent possible. I was hoping I could just do a bunch of `Solve`s and be done with it, but, apparently there's more to it.

Comment: I'm probably just getting paranoid but https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html no longer seems to mention the three argument form of Solve, unless the last argument is a domain... ok, it's apparently this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83902/how-to-eliminate-variables-when-using-solve

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?:

```
Solve[eqns, {az}, {ra}, Method -> Reduce]
(*
  {{az -> ArcTan[
      Cos[lat] Sin[dec] - Cos[dec] Cos[ha] Sin[lat], -Cos[dec] Sin[ha]]}}
*)
```

Or this, if an equation is preferred:

```
Reduce[eqns, {az}, {ra}]
(* az == ArcTan[Cos[lat] Sin[dec] - Cos[dec] Cos[ha] Sin[lat], -Cos[dec] Sin[ha]] *)
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve for `ha`, not `ra`. When I do that, neither `Reduce[eqns, az, {ha}]` nor `Solve[eqns, az, {ha}, Method -> Reduce]` works.

Comment: @barrycarter I didn't solve for `ra`.  The code you first used indicated you wanted to solve for `az` (and the code asks for `ha` to be eliminated, but I thought you meant the opposite): "should be easy... just replace gmst+lon-ra with ha in the az equation" and that's exactly what the above does, no?  (Apply `Equal @@@ ...`  to the result if you want an equation instead of a rule.  Or simply `Reduce[eqns, {az}, {gmst, lon, ra}]`.)

Comment: I might be fundamentally misunderstanding, but, despite what the docs appear to say, doesn't `Solve[eqns, az, {ha}]` mean "give me az in terms of ha"? If not, my whole question is a mistake.

Comment: @barrycarter When the third argument to `Solve` or `Reduce` is a list of variables, they try to eliminate those variables.  See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/behavior-of-reduce-with-variables-as-domain).  I believe they took that out of the docs some versions ago, when they added functionality to specify the domain with the third argument.